# angular.copy issue with Jasmine Test case

Tags: testing, jasmine, case

Request you to help me find the solution of below issue.
I have one function and corresponding Jasmine test case, like the one written below.
If I use angular.copy (and I have to use this only) in my function, Jasmine test case fails and error shown is expected 'originalValue' to equal 'newValue'.
If I use var obj = param1 (and not angular.copy) then Jasmine test case executes successfully. 
I have to use angular.copy and at the same time, want jasmine test case to pass. Please help.

### function

```
function func(param1, param2, condition)
{
var obj = angular.copy(param1);
if(condition){
obj.prop = param2;
}
}
```

### jasmine test case

```
it('xxxx', function(){
var param = {'prop': ''};
var obj = {'prop': 'orignialValue'};
func(param, 'newValue', true);
expect(obj.prop).toEqual('newValue');
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of doing angular.copy inside the function func, I am first doing angular.copy and then passing this copied object to function func as its first parameter (param1).

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided is incorrect.

```
it('xxxx', function(){
   var obj = {'prop': 'orignialValue'};
   func(param, 'newValue', true);
   expect(obj.prop).toEqual('newValue');
});
```

param is not defined over here, this should be obj I assume.

Since you use angular.copy, obj.prop is not added by ref to param1.

Comment: Hi, edited example by defining param. As I have to use angular copy only, is there any way my it block executes successfully? Please help. Thanks.